# 既存のデータベースをRealmで扱う場合

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Realm 初心者のため、見当違いな質問でしたら申し訳ありません。

現在、Excelで作成したデータベースをcsvに変換、SQLiteから読み込ませてiPhoneアプリで動かしています。ただ、１つのデータベース内に5000行ほどの情報があり、StringとBoolで文字、画像、音声などにつなげる仕様になっているため、動作が多少重く、Realmの導入を考えています。

このような既存のExcelデータをRealmで使用する場合は、csvやjsonに変換の上、Realmで読み込ませるという認識でよろしいのでしょうか。またどのような形式が最善かつ効率的なのでしょうか。

マニュアルを一通り読んでみたのですが、電話帳のような既存のデータをインポートし、表示させる方法がわからなかったため、質問させていただきました。

大変恐縮ではございますが、ご回答頂ければ幸いです。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

アプリケーションの要件によりますので、現在の情報からこれが最善かつ効率的、という方法を示すことはできませんが、
一般的には、現在SQLiteでやられているように、一旦ExcelのデータをCSVなどに変換してプログラムで扱えるようにして、Realmに保存して利用するのが良いです。

データが実行時に更新されないのであれば、シミュレータなどでデータのインポートを先にやっておいて、できたファイルをアプリに添付して直接読み込んで使用するのが簡単です。